# Сбой приложения при отключенном интернете

Tags: android, recyclerview, mvvm, android-data-binding

Делаю приложение с использованием архитектуры MVVM и, соответственно, DataBinding. У меня есть RecyclerView, куда через BindingAdapter сабмитится загружаемый лист с данными.
Но когда отключаю интернет и пытаюсь запустить приложение, оно просто крашится. В логах ничего нет, кроме FATAL EXCEPTION: main, процесса и его pid. Понимаю, что, скорее всего, ошибка в месте, где я пытаюсь забиндить данные, но что тогда делать с биндингом данных в RecyclerView, если при отсутствии интернета их попросту нет?

Comment: Попробуйте отловить исключение, через try catch

Answer (score 0):

Есть прекрасная конструкция `try catch`. Вы можете обернуть ваш вызов в  `try catch` и в случае ошибки показать пользователю какой-то экран ошибки. Что-то вроде такого:

```
try {
    loadDataFromNetwork()    
} catch (Exception ex) {
    showError()
}
```

[Вот](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1943-iskljuchenija-perekhvat-i-obrabotka) неплохой урок по этой теме.